# Transparent view on the stack

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, detailsview

I am trying to figure out my possibilities. I have a TableCellView with a disclosure button. When you hit the the disclosure button currently a viewcontroller is pushed on the stack with a picker. Here are some images.

[image: bar]
the disclosure button next to a TextField

[image: ib]
In IB, the view behind the picker has alpha set to 0.5 and opaque set to NO.
I naively thought this would show my view below.

[image: acctual]
In the simulator, not only do i not see my view below this one,
but my picker is affected by the transparent view behind it.

**The Point**
So I suppose my question is can I do what I am trying here and display the tableview with the disclosure button below the detail view, grayed out. If not, is there another approach not as boring as a UIAlertView or plain as showing just a picker.

Comment: did you really have to edit this just to remove 'thank you'. (rhetorical)

Comment: fobear Yep. I really do ;) There is a general policy of removing salutations on StackOverflow. I know sure they are included with the best intentions, but your question is much more useful to the internet without it.

Comment: fobear Would you prefer the 1.7 million SO questions with the "Hi There, Hello, Thanks, Cheers, Thanks for all your help, Much appreciated, Any help would be great" etc, or without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIViewController's views are expected to be opaque and fill their window. As a result you cannot stack them as you are attempting to do because the view you expect to see in the background will not be drawn and may have been unloaded entirely.

If you want to layer views like that you are going to have to add your transparent view as a subview of your UIViewController's view instead of pushing a new view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pushing a new view controller (which hides the previous view), use a modal view controller, and instead of setting the view's alpha to .5, set it's background color to a color with an alpha of .5, so the picker's opacity isn't affected.

Comment: the background trick worked to fix the picker isn't affected, however I am afraid Jonah is right about being opaque and filling the window, even for modal views.